# Query DocumentDB based on lambda expression func<TEntity, dynamic>

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, azure-cosmosdb

The requirement is to pass any custom expression query to the documentDB and fetch records based on it.

```
public Task<dynamic> ExecuteQuery(Func<TEntity, dynamic> lambda)
{
    dynamic result = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(documentCollectionUri).Where(lambda); //compile error
    return result;
}
```

above function can be called like this:

```
var res = await _locationDbRepository.ExecuteQuery(x => x.Name == "raja" && x.Address == "abc");
```

Clearly, it will give compile time error because `Where()` is expecting a `predicate` but, I need to pass a `func`. I don't want to pass `predicate` because it always return a boolean but `func` can return anything.

- A SQL query can be passed to documentDB but then I have to convert lambda expression to SQL query using a 3rd party library which I don't want to use.

The above approach to query `documentdb` is not working so Any other way you can suggest based on lambda expression?

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic`?

Comment: return type is not known at compile time so I'm using dynamic.

Comment: What if you change the parameter to: `Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> lambda`

Comment: You should use `object` instead. dynamic is not the right type for that

Comment: tried with expression also.. problem is with where() it is accepting Expression<Func<dynamic,bool>> predicate

Comment: Is it because you entered `client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>` dynamic here? Should it be `TEntity`?  _(never worked with DocumentDB)_

Comment: no.. it's not related to CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>, where() is an extension method which accepts predicate only.

Comment: Looks like the generic method fails here...

Comment: Where is a filter. How it is supposed to work with functions not returning bool? You have an example usage but there you also return bool. Please provide an example which does not return bool and explain how is it supposed to work.

Comment: @Evk you are basically asking for answer :P I was just showing what I did and I'm asking is there any other way... no need to use where() at all.

Comment: But just to be clear, what is the example of query you are going to pass which does not return bool? What is the expected syntax?

Comment: @Evk like (x => x.Name == "raja") should return all the records with name=raja

Comment: This expression also returns bool. It is Func<TEntity,  bool> (so, a predicate). I'm asking for example of when it is **not** predicate.

Comment: (Expression<Func<TEntity, List<string>>> lambda). This parameter is expecting  List<string> in return

Answer (score 3):

So, I figured out the solution by passing `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` as parameter and it's returning expected results based on the lambda expression.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetByExpression(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
        {
            IEnumerable<TEntity> IEnumerable;
            List<TEntity> List = new List<TEntity>();

            try
            {
                IDocumentQuery<TEntity> Queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(documentCollectionUri)
                                                 .Where(expression)
                                                 .AsDocumentQuery();

                while (Queryable.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (TEntity t in await Queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<TEntity>())
                    {
                        List.Add(t);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (DocumentClientException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            IEnumerable = List;
            return IEnumerable;
        }
```

It can be called like this:

```
dynamic results = SomeObj.GetByExpression(c=>c.Name== "raja" || c.Rank==12);
```

Comment: I have similar code, but I ran into an issue where 'TEntity' is a base class (but I want the properties of the super class).  So, I was trying to get the DocumentQuery to give me back a Document, so that I can deserialize it afterwards) i.e. doing IDocumentQuery<Document>, but then I can no longer pass "expression" to the .Where(expression) - do you have any suggestions?

Comment: make TEntity inherit the super class, then TEntity will have all the properties.